# Makefile FILES command will not execute

Tags: makefile

I am trying to learn Make syntax, I have instructed it to compile a file and it does this correctly, when I tell it to execute a shell command to create a file using touch it does not do this, it returns no error to indicate anything is wrong.

**Commands**

```
HelloWorld: HelloWorld.c
    gcc -o HelloWorld HelloWorld.c 

FILES="$(shell touch > file1.txt)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
 $(shell touch file1.txt)
```

(Notice the lack of a `>` redirect in there).    Also touch does not output anything to stdout, therefore `FILES` would be blank no matter what, so the assignment is useless.

If you're going to do things like this be aware that the `$(shell ...)` commands (in the global scope) are executed at parse time, before any of the recipes are run.

------------ EDIT -------------

In regards to your question about creating a blank file:

```
all:
$(info output $(shell echo "hello world"))
$(shell touch file1.txt)
```

should produce your file:

```
> ls file1.txt; make; ls file1.txt
file1.txt
output hello world
make-3.81: Nothing to be done for `all'.
file1.txt
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I am trying to get Make to create a blank file for me using the shell command. Is make not capable of doing this? I tried also to echo to the shell as a test but that also did nothing. Am I understanding Makes shell command correctly, it is used to run bash shell commands, right?

Comment: Yes, it's to run bash shell commands at parse time.   At parse time, make replaces the `$(shell)` command with it's output.   One use might be to set a variable such as `DATE:=$(shell date)`, which would expand to `DATE:=Mon Mar 18`, thereby setting the Makefile `DATE` variable.    You should typically avoid `$(shell)` commands with side effects such as creating files, etc.   That sort of thing should be done by recipes.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a recipe syntax that would create a blank text file?

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure why the touch command I gave you should create file1.txt if it is placed in the global scope of the makefile (I just tried it...).

Comment: Nope, I will simply forget about it, the make manual is so badly written it's driving me insane.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out already your syntax is wrong.  But beyond that your shell function is *never even executed*.

Why not?  Because in your makefile, you define a variable which contains the shell variable invocation but then you never *use* the variable anywhere.  Since you don't use it, the variable is never expanded.  Since the variable is never expanded, the function in it is never invoked.

If you want the variable to be expanded you either need to make it a simple variable (using `:=`) so that the right-hand side is expanded when the variable is assigned, or you have to use the function in a context where it's expanded immediately; the other answer has an example of using that (outside of any variable assignment)

Here's an example of using a simple variable:

```
HelloWorld: HelloWorld.c
        gcc -o HelloWorld HelloWorld.c 

FILES := $(shell touch file1.txt)
```

(note you don't need quotes when setting makefile variables, unlike shell variables).

As for the manual, it's written to be a user guide: that is you're supposed to read it starting at the beginning, rather than a reference manual where you jump around.  In particular you won't get anywhere writing makefiles until you read carefully and fully understand the initial two chapter "Introduction to Makefiles" and "Writing Makefiles".  For fluency you need to understand the section [How make Reads a Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html).